# How to replace a node in an n-ary tree in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tree

I have created an n-ary tree using python. Tree structure is following

```
class Tree:
    def __init__(self, data=None):
        self.data=data
        self.child=[]
```

I want to replace a node in a tree. I am using preorder traversal to find the node to replace. Following is the code to replace the node.

```
    def replace(self, root, node):
        if root is not None:
            if root.data == node.data:
               root=node
               root.child=node.child
               return
            for i in range(0,len(root.child)):
               self.replace(root.child[i], node)
```

In the replace function, node is the new "node" which i want to replace in the tree rooted at "root".

The above code doesn't replacing the node. before and after replace function, tree is same.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `data` and `child` are the only fields of the `Tree` object, then `root.child=node.child` in this case should be enough. So just remove `root=node` line as it just replaces local variable `root`.

Another note:

```
for child in root.child:
    self.replace(child, node)
```

would work the same as:

```
for i in range(0,len(root.child)):
    self.replace(root.child[i], node)
```

but the former is more Pythonic.